# Cordova Splash Screen?

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, splash-screen

Im doing an app using cordova, and Im trying to use the splash screen for android, but I don't know how to do it or if I have to install a plug-in, the splash screen for iOS is working fine.

Hoping some one can point me on the right direction on how to apply the splash screen for android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link : [Android splashscreen configuration in Cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_config.md.html#Android%20Configuration)

**SplashScreen (string, defaults to splash):** The name of the file minus its extension in the res/drawable directory. Various assets must share this common name in various subdirectories.

Just add this below line inside `config.xml` file :

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="mySplash"/>
```

**Note** : *`mySplash` will be a png file from res/drawable folders.*

Comment: the images inside the drawables are the splash images, because are the icon.png

Comment: Suppose the image name of splash is "splashImage.png" then you need to apply "value = splashImage" in <preference>.

Answer (score 1):

start splash in MainActivity:
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", splash_time_in_ms);

then stop it somewhere: 
navigator.splashscreen.hide();